# Using handicapped plackards from one state when vehicle is registered in another

Tags: vehicle

I walk past a vehicle every day parked in a handicapped spot that doesn't look usable by anyone I would consider handicapped (a very lifted jeep). I don't want to sound like the arbiter of what is handicapped, but I also consider it very rude and inconsiderate to use handicapped parking when you are not disabled.

I looked at the handicapped placard (on the dash of the jeep, not hanging from the mirror) and it is from Iowa and dosn't expire, but the jeep has Colorado tags. My question is, is that Iowa placard valid? Couldn't some unscrupulous person sell their dead grandparents "permanent" placard to someone out of state that allows them to park in the best spots all the time.

Comment: Ex-colleague of mine suffered from bad backpain after an accident and that kind of car was the only one he could drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the relevant code: https://www.legis.iowa.gov/docs/code/2016/321L.pdf (8 pages).

The permit is supposed to be returned to DMV if the person to whom it was issued dies or moves out of state (321L.3(1)(a) and (b)), but I see no requirement that the vehicle in which it is displayed must be tagged in Iowa.  It is also plausible that the jeep owner is driving a handicapped person around, since a placard may be used by a passenger.

On the other hand, the Colorado tags themselves may be illegal since people are supposed to register within 30 days of moving to Iowa (http://www.iowadot.gov/mvd/vehicleregistration/register.htm).  Iowa is a rather long commute from Colorado.